# Should this be a worldwide site or just USA?

Tags: discussion, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Home Improvement going to be tied to suggestions for one geography, or will it be appropriate for everywhere?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-home-improvement-going-to-be-tied-to-suggestions-for-one-geography-or-will-it)

Already there are lot of questions that assume the reader is in the USA and understands USA only language.

As it can also be very unsafe to connect UK wiring according to USA standared, should the site be xxx.CO.USA (rather then xxx.COM) to limit this problem?

Comment: Isn't this question the same as http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-home-improvement-going-to-be-tied-to-suggestions-for-one-geography-or-will-it ?

Comment: This should be a wiki

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are also a lot of overlap and for the site to be successful we need as many people as possible.